# PDF not loading When I click on a link in a website server in my WEBVIEW app

Tags: java, android, pdf, webview

I'm a newbie to android and I have made a webview android app. It belongs to a website . The website have many many pdf files in it, Which are in links . When I search a desirable file and found the file in my webview app and click on the link to open the pdf file it does not load pdf file . The link is embedded in a text like "view file". When I click on view file it does not load pdf file .

Thanks in advance if you have a solution to my question.

Comment: When you click on the link in a web browser, does the PDF display/get downloaded?  When you hover over the link in a web browser, (or right-click and choose "copy URL" or similar) is the link end in example.pdf or is it a link to a script page like fileid=1234?

Comment: it does nothing when I click on the pdf link.

Comment: But a strange thing It open in Real Me2 pro but not on RedMi note 3

Answer (score 0):

You can load pdf in webview like below

```
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                String googleDocs = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";

               view.loadUrl(googleDocs + url);

            } else {
                webView.loadUrl(url);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The main problem is that it loads in RealMe 2 pro but not in RedMi note 3 when I use only my coding.